# Matlab production server not accessible within local network

Tags: android, windows, matlab, server, lan

I have Android mobile phone and Windows PC connected to one wifi router. I'm trying to access Matlab production server(MPS) via REST API from phone, but always having connection timeout. Phone sending requests fine (checked with https://httpbin.org/post), and MPS accessible with port 9910 from localhost(checked with crome extension). I created rules for port 9910 in brandmauer which will permit all in/out connections but still nothing happens when I send POST request to my PC. Should I make some other rules in brandmauer(but I don't know what rules) or something else wrong?

**Update**

The problem was that my Windows PC was not visible/accessible in LAN network. Fixed it in wifi sharing settings.

Comment: Try from a browser on your phone.

Comment: Try from a browser on the different pc as the one where your server is running on.